# How to use VB and SQL to add Records to a Relational Database in Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, relational-database

I'm working in Visual Basic to create a forms applications as part of a college project. I've used SQL statements to read from the access database but I'm having some trouble writing to it. I'd like to hazard a guess it's due to the database having relationships between tables.

This is my first go at making something substantial, and vb is not my language of choice. Expect the code to be poor at best. If anyone has links to resources that I could use to improve I'd be immensely grateful.

Exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'
>
> Exception location: 'commAddToStaff.ExecuteNonQuery()'

Both try statements are catching exceptions when ran. I've attempted providing data in the parameters rather than using data from a text box, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Code:

```vb
Private Sub btnAddStaffMember_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddStaffMember.Click

    'Dimension tblStaff Parameters 
    Dim AddEmployeeIDParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddEmployeeID", txtAddEmployeeID.Text)
    Dim AddForenameParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddForename", txtAddForename.Text)
    Dim AddSurnameParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddSurname", txtAddSurname.Text)
    Dim AddDOBParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddDOB", txtAddDOB.Text)
    Dim AddUserTierParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddUserTier", txtAddUserTier.Text)

    'Dimension tblContacts Parameters
    Dim conContact As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.......")
    Dim commContactCount As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select Count(*) FROM tblContacts", conContact)
    commContactCount.Connection.Open()                 
    Dim ContactID = commContactCount.ExecuteScalar + 1     'Calculate the contactID of the new record
    commContactCount.Connection.Close()                  'Close the connection
    Dim AddContactIDParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddContactID", ContactID)
    Dim AddAddressParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddAddress", txtAddAddress.Text)
    Dim AddPostcodeParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddPostcode", txtAddPostcode.Text)
    Dim AddEmailParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddEmail", txtAddEmail.Text)
    Dim AddMobileNoParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AddMobileNo", txtAddMobileNumber.Text)

    Dim conAddToStaff As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft....")
    Dim commAddToStaff As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert Into tblStaff (EmployeeID, Forename, Surname, DOB, User_Tier, ContactID) Values (@AddEmployeeID, @AddForename, @AddSurname, @AddDOB, @AddUserTier, @AddContactID)", conAddToStaff)
    commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddEmployeeIDParam)
    commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddForenameParam)
    commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddSurnameParam)
    commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddDOBParam)
    commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddUserTierParam)

    Dim commAddToContact As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert Into tblContacts (ContactID, Address, Postcode, Email, Mobile_Number) Values (@AddContactID, @AddAddress, @AddPostcode, @AddEmail, @AddMobileNo)", conContact)
    commAddToContact.Parameters.Add(AddContactIDParam)
    commAddToContact.Parameters.Add(AddAddressParam)
    commAddToContact.Parameters.Add(AddPostcodeParam)
    commAddToContact.Parameters.Add(AddEmailParam)
    commAddToContact.Parameters.Add(AddMobileNoParam)

    Try
        commAddToStaff.Connection.Open()                 'Open a connection to the database
        commAddToStaff.ExecuteNonQuery()                 'Execute the command
        commAddToStaff.Connection.Dispose()              'Remove unmanaged resources
        commAddToStaff.Connection.Close()                'Close the connection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error with staff")
    End Try

    Try
        commAddToContact.Connection.Open()                 'Open a connection to the database
        commAddToContact.ExecuteNonQuery()                 'Execute the command
        commAddToContact.Connection.Dispose()              'Remove unmanaged resources
        commAddToContact.Connection.Close()                'Close the connection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error with contacts")
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("Reached")

    Me.Hide()       'Close the Current screen
    StaffDB_Add_Staff_Security_Question.Show()  'Open the Add Security Question Screen
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the actual error message? That will tell you and us what to look for. The fact that you appear not to know what it is indicates that you haven't actually tried to solve the problem yet. How could you if you don;t know what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I included that. I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, I'm really new to this. I've added what I think to be the error message above.

Comment: I've updated above, it occurs both times I attempt to ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting six values into six columns here:

```vb
Dim commAddToStaff As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert Into tblStaff (EmployeeID, Forename, Surname, DOB, User_Tier, ContactID) Values (@AddEmployeeID, @AddForename, @AddSurname, @AddDOB, @AddUserTier, @AddContactID)", conAddToStaff)
```

but you only add five parameters to the command here:

```vb
commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddEmployeeIDParam)
commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddForenameParam)
commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddSurnameParam)
commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddDOBParam)
commAddToStaff.Parameters.Add(AddUserTierParam)
```

Where's the parameter for the `@AddContactID` placeholder in the SQL code?

EDIT:

For the record, here's how I would tend to write code for that sort of task, ignoring the horrible way you're generating the `ContactID` value:

```vb
Using connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here")
    connection.Open()

    Dim contactCount As Integer

    Using contactCountCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblContacts", connection)
        contactCount = CInt(contactCountCommand.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using

    Dim contactId = contactCount + 1

    Using staffCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblStaff (EmployeeID, Forename, Surname, DOB, User_Tier, ContactID) Values (@EmployeeID, @Forename, @Surname, @DOB, @User_Tier, @ContactID)", connection)
        With staffCommand.Parameters
            .Add("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddEmployeeID.Text
            .Add("@Forename", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddForename.Text
            .Add("@Surname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddSurname.Text
            .Add("@DOB", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(txtAddDOB.Text) 'Why isn't this coming from a DateTimePicker?
            .Add("@User_Tier", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddUserTier.Text
            .Add("@ContactID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = contactId
        End With

        staffCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    Using contactCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblContacts (ContactID, Address, Postcode, Email, Mobile_Number) Values (@ContactID, @Address, @Postcode, @Email, @Mobile_Number)", connection)
        With contactCommand.Parameters
            .Add("@ContactID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = contactId
            .Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddAddress.Text
            .Add("@Postcode", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddPostcode.Text
            .Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddEmail.Text
            .Add("@Mobile_Number", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddMobileNumber.Text
        End With

        contactCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I've added that slightly further down, I calculate what the ContactID should be by counting the number of records in the contacts table then adding 1.

Comment: Nope. Read what I posted. That code shows you creating a parameter object. Where are you adding that parameter to that command? You aren't. You add it to the other command but not the one I specified in the words I wrote in my answer. Part of the problem is that your code is so verbose that it's hard to read and thus it's hard to see when it's wrong.

Comment: You might like to check out my suggestion on how to to write more concise, readable and maintainable code.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look into it. With the exception of some very basic python I'm completely new to coding so I'm gravely out of my depth. What I'm writing at the moment is closer to a collection of bodges than anything resembling eloquent. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Ian You might like a slightly different way of creating the SQL parameters as shown in my now-redundant answer. Also, make sure to use a Date in the database for the DOB, not a string.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney, the example you gave is much appreciated. I'll try to borrow from that style going forward, especially with the usage of the 'with' statements.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to see where there are insufficient parameters added by rearranging the code into smaller pieces, where related items are near to each other. Something like:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft......."

    Sub AddStaffMemberToDatabase(contactId As Integer)
        Dim sql = "INSERT INTO tblStaff (EmployeeID, Forename, Surname, DOB, UserTier, ContactID) VALUES (@AddEmployeeID, @AddForename, @AddSurname, @AddDOB, @AddUserTier, @AddContactID)"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

            Dim dob = DateTime.Parse(txtAddDOB.Text)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddEmployeeID", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 20, .Value = txtAddEmployeeID.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddForename", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 255, .Value = txtAddForename.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddSurname", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 255, .Value = txtAddSurname.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddDOB", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = dob})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddUserTier", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 20, .Value = txtAddUserTier.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddContactID", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer, .Value = contactId})

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    End Sub

    Sub AddContactToDatabase(contactId As Integer)
        Dim sql = "INSERT INTO tblContacts (ContactID, Address, Postcode, Email, Mobile_Number) VALUES (@AddContactID, @AddAddress, @AddPostcode, @AddEmail, @AddMobileNo)"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddContactID", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer, .Value = contactId})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddAddress", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 255, .Value = txtAddAddress.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@txtAddPostcode", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 20, .Value = txtAddPostcode.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddEmail", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 255, .Value = txtAddEmail.Text})
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AddMobileNo", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar, .Size = 20, .Value = txtAddMobileNumber.Text})

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    End Sub

    Sub AddStaffMember()
        Dim sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblContacts"
        Dim contactID As Integer

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            conn.Open()
            contactID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) + 1
        End Using

        AddStaffMemberToDatabase(contactID)
        AddContactToDatabase(contactID)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddStaffMember_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddStaffMember.Click
        AddStaffMember()
        Me.Hide()
        StaffDB_Add_Staff_Security_Question.Show()  'Open the Add Security Question Screen

    End Sub

End Class
```

The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement makes sure that "unamanaged resources" are released when the code has finished with them.

Note that you will need to provide a more specific and robust way of parsing the DOB text (e.g. DateTime.TryParseExact). Also, the database types and sizes need to be edited to match the declarations in the database.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I was unaware that you could specify the data types and sizes like that. I think I'm going to rewrite the code from scratch borrowing for both of these answers. Everything I've got so far is comprised of blocks that I've picked up online and forced together piecemeal, definitely in need of improvement. Thanks again!