# How to Update Database Datetime in This Format " dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT' "With Vb.net Program

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I Searched a lot about how to Get The Time online and i found a solution You will found it in my Codes.

> My Aim is to make a MemberShip DateTime , **First Step** to make the program **get the Time from internet** `startdate` then **add** the Time which is the membership time as `enddate`,**Second Step** when the program run again it will **replace** the start time with the actual time **"Got from internet too"** and **substract** it with the `enddate`

**Here is My Database Structure** (Note i tried to make the `enddate` and `startdate` As `DateTime` but it failed):

[image: Database Structure]

**Here is my Program :**

[[image: Program Photo]]

here is my code :

```vb
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Net
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Public Class Form1
    Dim date1 As DateTime
    Dim date2 As DateTime
    Dim date3 As DateTime
    Dim x As DateTime
    Public Shared Function GetNistTime() As DateTime
        Dim myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com"), HttpWebRequest)

        Dim response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim todaysDates As String = response.Headers("date")
        Return DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        x = GetNistTime()
        TextBox1.Text = x

        date1 = CStr(x.AddMonths(1))
        Dim MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=123456789;database=test"
        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim Query As String
        Dim sqlcommand As MySqlCommand
        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Query = "UPDATE test.time SET startdate='" & x & "',enddate='" & date1 & "' WHERE username='program'"
            sqlcommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
            Reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MySqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=123456789;database=test"
        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim Query As String
        Dim sqlcommand As MySqlCommand
        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Query = "Select * from test.time  WHERE username='program'"
            sqlcommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
            Reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader
            While Reader.Read
                date2 = Reader.GetDateTime("startdate")
                date3 = Reader.GetDateTime("enddate")
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MySqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
        TextBox2.Text = date2
        TextBox3.Text = date3
    End Sub
End Class
```

**When i Run the Program and Press** `button2` **I got this Error:**

[[image: Program Error Photo]]

**then when i press ok on ex.message this writen in** `TextBox2` **&** `TextBox3`**:**

[[image: Program Error Photo]]

**This is the out put which stored in the Database:**

[[image: The Out Put in Database]]

**Please Help Me And Edit anything you Want in code or here,  if you have another Idea Let me know it, sorry if i put All the Details and seem boring,thanks**

**i Know a way to replace "ص" or "م" to "AM" and "PM" If you have Any way to get the Date with "Am" and "PM" directly i would be Grateful**

Comment: "i tried to make the enddate and startdate As DateTime but it failed" <- you should resolve that first. When that's fixed, change your update sql to use parameters. Also worth using `Using` for any objects that need to be disposed.

Comment: This is not a Big problem Because The startdate or enddate don`t accept the AM or PM that shows me An Error So i make it Varchar ! so is there any Way to Fix the Format of the date and Send it ?@AndrewMortimer

Comment: Dates are dates, and strings are strings. If you want to store a date, use a date column.

Comment: **I get the Date Like That :** 20/05/2020 07:31:19 ص  
**And SQL accept it Like That:** 2020-05-15 07:31:19 **What i can do** @AndrewMortimer

Comment: @AndrewMortimer and i want to Substract Two Dates From Time To Time i want to have a Substractable Date , What Should I do

Comment: @EslamAlawy The `&` will convert the datetimes to strings, which is not what you want. To prevent that, use SQL parameters to pass the data. Also, I suspect you meant `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` so that it gets the UTC date (I tested it).

Comment: so please if you tested it what is the selution you wrote in your code ,can you give me it !

Comment: @EslamAlawy Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear there: I only tested the DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal part.

Comment: so do you mean prametars like this in selution ?:
`MyCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE SeansMessage SET Message = @TicBoxText WHERE Number = 1", dbConn)
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicBoxText", TicBoxText.Text)`

Comment: @EslamAlawy You can see how to use SQL parameters in [this answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60914324/1115360). You will need to change the names from "OleDbConnection" to "MySqlConnection" and so on.

Comment: @EslamAlawy Yes, that is going in the right direction, but don't use AddWithValue as that can lead to other problems: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: ok but is this will prevent "ص" from appear after the Hour Time !@AndrewMorton

Comment: @AndrewMorton brother you seem kind , do you know any way else to achive my AIm !
you can know my aim if you read the first lines of this problem

Comment: @EslamAlawy You can control exactly how the datetime appears as text by using  ToString as shown in [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Also, you need to use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) so that Visual Studio can tell you where variable types do not match.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i used this but i got Error my Code : 

` sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@addStartDate", .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = x})
            sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@addEndDate", .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = date1})
`
Error ** System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. sqlcommand was Nothing.**

Comment: i solved it by putting  `As New`

Comment: @AndrewMorton i have another problem : 
the program Successfully reached to the database and updated the value of Start Date and End Date but with false values : like this 
`0000-00-00 00:00:00` for start date  and `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for end date

Comment: @EslamAlawy If you could [edit] your question to add the code as it is at the moment, it would be easier for us.